# Avastar SP88W8782 wifi module Pinout 12 pin usb

Tags: wifi

[image]I just opened a HP wifi driven printer and found an Marvell Avastar 88W8782 Wifi Module with 12 Pin connector to the main board. From googling I found that this is a USB interface driven module but I cannot find a datasheet with any pinout info. This module is suppose to have a Uart and also a spi bus. Does anyone has any idea on how to use this module?
Only datasheet I am end up with is [enter link description here](http://www.marvell.com/wireless/avastar/88W8782/index.jsp)

Comment: HP and Marvell would know.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Too bad these companies advertise about recycling and saving the planet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the pinout on Aliexpress:
[image]

Some links that may help you:

http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Marvell-88w8782-chip-sdio-interface-high-performance-low-power-small-size-wifi-wireless-module/924751_1793202293.html

See Download section in the following link, download Application notes zip:
http://www.embeddedworks.net/wlan493.html

check out the pdf file named 88MC200_Hardware_Design_Guide (MV-S302321-00) inside the zip file. (page 15) It talks about interfacing a microcontroller to this WiFi module.

Comment: That seems to be a different module from the one that the O.P. has got.  I would imagine that firmware, command protocol, behavior are different.  Overall, trying to reuse a salvaged module like the one in the O.P. is a wrong use of one's time.

Comment: The model number is the same as the one O.P. has got, I only tried to find anything related since the only datasheet doesn't give much of information. I also agree with you, there are open source modules that can be used instead of this one. I would recommend ESP8266 for example.